# Implementation of variadic map function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, variadic-functions, map-function

As you can see in the example below, map function in Scheme is variadic function.

```
> (map (lambda (number1 number2)
     (+ number1 number2))
   '(1 2 3 4)
   '(10 100 1000 10000))
'(11 102 1003 10004)
```

I want to implement this variadic option, but I only succeeded to find the two arguments map implementation:

```
(define (map f lst)
   (if (null? lst)
       '()
       (cons (f (car lst)) (map f (cdr lst)))))
```

Can someone help me implement variadic map function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Scheme, you can write a variadic function as `(lambda x ...)`, in which case `x` gets bound to the entire list of arguments, or by using an improper lambda list, e.g., `(lambda (a b c . ds) ...)`, which takes *at least* three arguments, and binds `ds` to the list of the remaining arguments.  The code you're trying to write, then, would be something like (I'm writing in R5RS Scheme):

```
(define (my-map function list1 . more-lists)
  (define (some? function list)
    ;; returns #f if (function x) returns #t for 
    ;; some x in the list
    (and (pair? list)
         (or (function (car list))
             (some? function (cdr list)))))
  (define (map1 function list)
    ;; non-variadic map.  Returns a list whose elements are
    ;; the result of calling function with corresponding
    ;; elements of list
    (if (null? list)
        '()
        (cons (function (car list))
              (map1 function (cdr list)))))
  ;; Variadic map implementation terminates
  ;; when any of the argument lists is empty
  (let ((lists (cons list1 more-lists)))
    (if (some? null? lists)
        '()
        (cons (apply function (map1 car lists))
              (apply my-map function (map1 cdr lists))))))
```

This works as expected:

```
(my-map + '(0 2 5) '(1 2 3))
;=> (1 4 8)
```

Notice that to make this work, we needed a non-variadic `map` (here called `map1`) in order to do `(map1 car lists)` to get the argument list to call `function` with, and `(map1 cdr lists)` to get the rests of the lists to recurse with.  To write a variadic `map` (here called `my-map`), you already need an implementation of the non-variadic `map`.

Comment: I think you can get rid of `list1` and only have `(my-map function . lists)`. This means you can also remove the `let` and simplify the implementation.

Comment: @mihai Changing the definition to `(define (my-map function . lists) ...)`allows the call `(my-map function)`. It's not clear what should return. [R5RS Scheme](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_558) and [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) both require at least one list argument, so I followed that convention here, too.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice observation. I haven't thought about that. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your answer but note that there is a syntactic keyword `case-lambda` that lets you be explicit about the procedure to use when the number or arguments varies.  You'd use it like this:

```
(define my-map
  (case-lambda
   ((func list) …)
   ((func list1 list2) …)
   (…)
   ((func . lists) …)))
```

This way, you can optimize your handling of different argument counts.  The `case-lambda` generates a 'wrapping lambda' that essentially looks like this (but might be compiled more efficiently):

```
(define my-map
  (lambda args ;; illustration only, implementations vary.
    (apply (let ((len (length args)))
             (cond ((= 2 len) (lambda (func list) …))
                   …))
           args)))
```

Comment: I like this;  I was trying to keep my answer in R5RS (for portability), but this is a nice piece of functionality to know about for Racket.

Comment: R6RS and R7RS.  Easily defined with define-syntax (see R7RS appendix for one definition).