# Custom map function - how does it work?

Tags: recursion, scheme, variadic-functions, map-function

**I apologize for the unclear topic title.**

I have this function in Scheme which is a custom implementation of the `map` function. It works fine, but I got lost trying to understand it.

```
(define (my-map proc . ls)
  (letrec ((iter (lambda (proc ls0)
                   (if (null? ls0)
                       '()
                       (cons (proc (car ls0)) 
                             (iter proc (cdr ls0))))))
           (map-rec (lambda (proc ls0)
                     (if (memq '() ls0)
                         '()
                         (cons (apply proc (iter car ls0)) 
                               (map-rec proc (iter cdr ls0)))))))
    (map-rec proc ls)))
```

The problem lays in `cons (proc (car ls0))`. If I'm correct, when passing `(1 2 3) (4 5 6)` to the `ls` parameter the actual value of it will be `((1 2 3) (4 5 6))`. Therefore `iter car ls0` in `map-rec` will pass `(1 2 3)` to `iter`. Hence `proc (car ls0)` in `iter` will have the form: `(car (car (1 2 3)))`, but this is impossible, right?

I know my thinking is flawed somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Implementation of variadic map function in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21629203/1281433) which discusses how to implement the `map` that accepts multiple lists in terms of the `map` that accepts only a single list.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll surely look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to understand the procedure:

- The `iter` helper is the same as `map`, but operating on a single list.
- The `map-rec` helper generalizes `iter`, working for a list of lists, stopping when at least one of the lists is empty
- This part: `(apply proc (iter car ls0))` applies the procedure on the first element of each list; the call to `iter` creates a list of the `car` part of the lists
- And this part: `(map-rec proc (iter cdr ls0))` simultaneously advances the recursion over all the lists; the call to `iter` creates a list of the `cdr` part of the lists

Perhaps renaming the procedures will make things clear. Here's a completely equivalent implementation, making explicit the fact that `map-one` operates on a single list and `map-many` operates on a list of lists:

```
(define (map-one proc lst)  ; previously known as `iter`
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (proc (car lst))
            (map-one proc (cdr lst)))))

(define (map-many proc lst) ; previously known as `map-rec`
  (if (memq '() lst)
      '()
      (cons (apply proc (map-one car lst))
            (map-many proc (map-one cdr lst)))))

(define (my-map proc . lst) ; variadic version of `map-many`
  (map-many proc lst))
```

It works just like the original `my-map`:

```
(my-map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
=> '(12 15 18)
```

And you can check that `map-one` is really a `map` that works on a single list:

```
(map-one (lambda (x) (* x x))
         '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 4 9 16 25)
```

See the effect of `(map-one car lst)` on a list of lists:

```
(map-one car '((1 4 5) (2 6 7) (3 8 9)))
=> '(1 2 3)
```

Likewise, see how `(map-one cdr lst)` works:

```
(map-one cdr '((1 4 5) (2 6 7) (3 8 9)))
=> '((4 5) (6 7) (8 9))
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why, but I thought that `(map-one car lst)` will pass the `car` of the list of lists (that is, the first list) to `map-one`, but it will of course pass the whole thing, so `(car (car lst))` will return the first item of the inside list.